# Is there an easy way to see if a firm is union or non-union?

Tags: stocks

I've decided I want to move away from index mutual funds and pick the stocks myself. One of the criteria I have is whether or not the firm is union. Is there an easy and reliable way to find this information out? Also, I know some companies are partially unionized. It would be good to be able to find out what the proportion is.

Comment: Remember that an international company is likely to have different union policies in different parts of the world. They are also likely to have different union policies for different kinds of workers. This won't be a simple question. Also you may have to distinguish between those that permit union activity (open shop) and those that compel it (closed shop).

Comment: That probably would also apply to different states within the USA - the same company could have unionized branches in one state and non-unionized in another. See, for example, recent controversy about Boeing's unionized plant in Washington and non-unionized one in South Carolina.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to find out is to ask the company itself. If you read annual reports, there are often mentions of union activities/involvement there. You can also google "[company name] labor union" to see what comes up - news articles generally identify whether the company has a union or not.

But again, the simplest way would be to call/e-mail investor relations at a company and ask about union status.